# Set a diverging color scheme to center on zero in Altair

Tags: python, visualization, altair

How can I go about getting the colour scale to center on zero for a diverging colour scale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can now use `domainMid=0`.

Adapting the example from @jakevdp:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 3), columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])
alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(
    x='x',
    y='y',
    color=alt.Color('z', scale=alt.Scale(scheme='blueorange', domainMid=0))
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to explicitly set the domain to be symmetric:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 3), columns=['x', 'y', 'z'])
alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(
  x='x',
  y='y',
  color=alt.Color('z', scale=alt.Scale(scheme='blueorange', domain=[-3, 3]))
)
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, perfect! Simple solution. I was hoping there would be a center as in seaborn for example, but this also works, although it's a pain if the values are skewed heavily towards either extreme.

Comment: We do plan to add scale.domainMid to Vega-Lite/Altair, but haven't got the time to do it yet. You can follow the thread here https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/4542. Contributions are also welcomed. :)